# href with "#", is it bad practice?

Tags: jquery, html, unobtrusive-javascript

[The CSS Markup Detective](http://www.red-root.com/sandbox/holmes/) suggests to improve the markup when there are links with href=#.

Having href=# is a bad practice or bad markup? In some situations, esp. with respect to unobtrusive this is the only way, right?

Here is an example that needs to be improved:

```
<a href="#">Cancel</a>
```

Comment: Do you mean <a href="#"></a> - as in, a link that is ONLY a hash - or do you mean href 'with' # as in a link address containing a hash? Your subject line and question seem to disagree...

Comment: @Dylan, added an example

Comment: SO uses it for the star on the left: `<a class="star-off" href="#" title="This is a favorite question (click again to undo)">favorite</a>`

Comment: The Yahoo homepage uses it 3 times...

Comment: @Šime: SO seems to be also confused with what to do. For instance, the "close" link doesn't have any `href`: `<a id="close-question-5820027" title="..">close</a>`

Comment: @thirtydot Yea, they should've added `href="#"` on the "close" and "flag" links to make them TAB-able.

Answer (score 5):

It's considered a bad practice since it is meaningless without JavaScript. If you have links with only a # as the href, then you are probably relying on JavaScript to execute when that link is interacted with. So basically, you should do one of the following things:

1. Create a proper URL that mimics the action that the JavaScript would do. This allows users with JavaScript disabled to still access the functionality. If JavaScript is enabled, you can just intercept the click, cancel the default action (navigation to the link url), and do your usual progressive enhancement logic.
2. Add the link dynamically with JavaScript upon page load if you don't have a fallback or can't make that functionality work without JavaScript. This way a user with JavaScript disabled will not be able to see links that won't work for him anyway. You could couple this with `<noscript>` tags to inform the user that he is missing out on some of the functionality of your site by having JavaScript disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bad practice. Just to leave it when in production, finally, is a bad practice. And if you are working with labels inside the page, it's a good practice too.

Answer (score 0):

I use href="javascript:;" if this is required.  Using href="#" treats the anchor as an anchor within the current page and can cause undesired behavior (such as a window/frame scrolling to the top on click).

Answer (score 0):

It's not bad practice, and it's better than `href='javascript:;'`. If you want to stop the page from 'jumping' cancel the propagation of the click event or return false from the onclick function.